# Windows Phone pivot header at bottom xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to have the header at the bottom of the pivot control, but i cant control the position of PivotHeaderPanel, any one have a solution for this?

I have tried pivot.headertemplate but that didnt seem to Work and i did try to edit the pivot control template but that didnt Work either

```
<PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
        <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
        </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
    </ItemsPresenter>
    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
        <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
        </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
    </PivotHeaderPanel>
</PivotPanel>
```

Comment: You might share your attempt at the template and I'd bet we can help sort you out. You're literally just moving around the Primitives:PivotHeadersControl down below your item presenter.

Comment: Tried it but did'nt Work

<PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
  <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
   <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>  </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
 </ItemsPresenter>
 <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
  <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>   <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform> </PivotHeaderPanel>
 </PivotPanel>

Comment: Throw that in an edit to your question amigo, not as a comment so folks can read it easier.  ....oh and I don't think we're talking about the same template, you want the style template.

Comment: Right click the Pivot in your Document Outline, Choose Edit Template>Edit a Copy, you need the actual Style template at your disposal, no worries.